# Is it safe to install libstdc++6:i386 on machine which already has libstdc++6:amd64?

Tags: package-management

Is it safe to install libstdc++6:i386 on machine which already has libstdc++6:amd64? 
I mean will i386 libs overwrite the existing amd64-libs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't actually done this myself, but I'm guessing no, it won't. To see why I'm guessing this, run `locate libstdc++`.

Comment: Yes, that's great. Now I see that both 32-bit and 64-bit libs stand together. Thanks a lot!